# Microsoft Graph Office 365 Reports - SfbActivity Discrepencies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot_sfbactivity), this endpoint can be used with a date parameter to select point-in-time statistics:

> [date] specifies the day to a view of the users that performed an
>   activity on that day. Must have a format of YYYY-MM-DD. Only available
>   for the last 30 days and is ignored unless view type is Detail

The following endpoint seems to suggest that there were 14 users performing Skype activities on the 10th March (as per the `Last activity date (UTC)` column):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',period='D30')/content
```

Response:

```
Data as of,User principal name,Deleted,Deleted date,Last activity date (UTC),P2P - total sessions,Conference organized - total sessions,Conference participated - total sessions,P2P - last activity date,Conference organized - last activity date,Conference participated - Last activity date,P2P - IM,P2P - audio,P2P - audio minutes,P2P - video,P2P - video minutes,P2P - app sharing,P2P - file transfers,Conference organized - IM,Conference organized - audio/video,Conference organized - audio/video minutes,Conference organized - app sharing,Conference organized - web,Conference organized dial-in/out 3rd party,Conference organized dial-in/out Microsoft,Conference organized dial-in Microsoft minutes,Conference organized dial-out Microsoft minutes,Conference participated - IM,Conference participated - audio/video,Conference participated - audio/video minutes,Conference participated - app sharing,Conference participated - web,Conference participated - dial-in,Products assigned,Reporting period in days
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,70,0,0,2017-03-10,,2016-10-17,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,30,0,4,2017-03-10,2017-02-28,2017-03-10,14,16,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,115,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,21,0,0,2017-03-10,,2017-02-02,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,33,0,0,2017-03-10,2017-01-20,2017-02-02,31,2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,207,3,16,2017-03-10,2017-03-09,2017-03-10,153,40,388,1,16,0,14,1,3,247,1,0,0,6,0,27,7,15,1127,6,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,123,0,2,2017-03-10,2017-02-20,2017-03-10,113,7,31,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,15,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,49,2,5,2017-03-10,2017-03-09,2017-03-09,43,5,33,0,0,0,1,2,2,51,0,0,0,4,0,0,2,4,313,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,47,0,0,2017-03-10,2016-12-12,2017-02-21,33,5,82,0,0,1,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,199,2,4,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,2017-03-09,163,33,256,8,101,2,1,1,2,29,0,0,0,4,0,0,3,3,114,2,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,3,0,1,2017-03-10,2017-01-09,2017-03-10,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,18,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,51,0,0,2017-03-10,2017-02-28,2017-03-01,34,6,51,0,0,2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,110,0,0,2017-03-10,2017-01-31,2017-01-31,104,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,34,1,5,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,26,8,7,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,5,178,2,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,92,3,5,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,81,5,59,0,0,2,4,0,3,41,1,0,0,6,0,0,0,5,83,1,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-03-08,4,0,2,2017-03-03,2017-02-15,2017-03-08,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,84,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-31,[redacted],False,,2017-01-20,0,0,0,2017-01-20,2017-01-05,2017-01-05,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
[truncated]
```

However, querying the point-in-time endpoint for the 10th only returns two of those users:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',date='2017-03-10')/content
```

Response:

```
Data as of,User principal name,Deleted,Deleted date,Last activity date (UTC),P2P - total sessions,Conference organized - total sessions,Conference participated - total sessions,P2P - last activity date,Conference organized - last activity date,Conference participated - Last activity date,P2P - IM,P2P - audio,P2P - audio minutes,P2P - video,P2P - video minutes,P2P - app sharing,P2P - file transfers,Conference organized - IM,Conference organized - audio/video,Conference organized - audio/video minutes,Conference organized - app sharing,Conference organized - web,Conference organized dial-in/out 3rd party,Conference organized dial-in/out Microsoft,Conference organized dial-in Microsoft minutes,Conference organized dial-out Microsoft minutes,Conference participated - IM,Conference participated - audio/video,Conference participated - audio/video minutes,Conference participated - app sharing,Conference participated - web,Conference participated - dial-in,Products assigned,Reporting period in days
2017-03-10,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,2,1,1,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,1,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,[truncated]
2017-03-10,[redacted],False,,2017-03-10,28,1,1,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,2017-03-10,23,3,34,0,0,1,1,0,1,22,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,22,0,0,0,[truncated]
```

Digging around, it looks like this endpoint might be going off the `Conference organized - last activity date` column. Is this a bug, or by design? How do I find how many conferences a user participated in for that day, if they did not organise any?

**Bonus Skype Question**

For my Office 365 tenant, the following endpoint suggests that there were no active Skype users on the 24th March:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/Office365ActiveUsers(view='Users',period='D30')/content
```

Response:

```
Data as of,Office 365,Exchange,OneDrive,SharePoint,Skype For Business,Yammer,Last activity date (UTC),Reporting period in days
[truncated]
2017-03-31,1,,,1,,,2017-03-23,30
2017-03-31,1,1,,,,,2017-03-24,30
2017-03-31,1,1,,,,,2017-03-25,30
```

However, the corresponding PowerShell cmdlet says otherwise:

[image: PowerShell results 24th]

It appears as though PSTN is no longer classified as a Skype activity - can this be confirmed? Or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

For the original question: recently we fixed an issue for Skype activity report, mainly to include all the daily active users when you include the "date" parameter. Previously, the daily list is somehow not complete, so the numbers don't match, and the Last Activity Date also don't match.

For the bonus question: the answer is yes, PSTN is currently not included in the Skype activity report.